Django-ninja Webhook Server - Signature Error/Bad Request
I am working on a Django application where I have to develop a webhook server using Django-ninja. The webhook app receives a new order notification as described here: https://developer.wolt.com/docs/marketplace-integrations/restaurant-advanced#webhook-server
My code below:
@api.post("/v1/wolt-new-order")
def wolt_new_order(request: HttpRequest):

    received_signature = request.headers.get('wolt-signature')
    if not received_signature:
        print("Missing signature")
        return HttpResponse('Missing signature', status=400)


    payload = request.body


    expected_signature = hmac.new(
        CLIENT_SECRET.encode(),
        payload,
        hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()
    
    print(f"Received: {received_signature}")
    print(f"Expected: {expected_signature}")


    if not hmac.compare_digest(received_signature, expected_signature):
        return HttpResponse('Invalid signature', status=400)

    print(payload)

    return HttpResponse('Webhook received', status=200)

For some reason this always returns 'error code 400, bad request syntax' and the two signatures are always different.
I am importing the CLIENT_SECRET correctly and I have all the necessary libraries properly installed.
Funny enough when I do the same on a test Flask app, I receive the webhook notification correctly without issues.
Flask code below:
import hmac
import hashlib
from flask import Flask, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1/wolt-new-order', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    # Extract the wolt-signature header
    received_signature = request.headers.get('wolt-signature')
    
    print(received_signature)

    # Extract the request payload
    payload = request.get_data()
    
    print(payload)

    # Compute the expected signature
    expected_signature = hmac.new(
        CLIENT_SECRET.encode(),
        payload,
        hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()
    
    print(expected_signature)

    # Compare signatures
    if not hmac.compare_digest(received_signature, expected_signature):
        abort(400, 'Invalid signature')

    
    print(payload)

    return 'Webhook received', 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)

My webhook server is behind ngrok. Any ideas?
What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Could you please provide the Flask code so I can compare? The code for the webhook you provided seems to be fine.

Sure @eternal_white, I have updated my post above with the Flask code. Please let me know what you think.

Howdy, sorry for replying late. I've tested both codes with Django and Flask using Postman, sent the exact same request, both gave the same signature. Could you please provide more details? The only different thing that the servers would receive is the payload, so compare the payloads on both, flask and django, and see if the payload is different. One different character will change the whole signature.
At this point it's an issue related to Wolt's implementation of the webhook, and not a Django problem.

Thank you @eternal_white. Apparently, the signature mismatch in my environment, comes from the fact that the payload in the case of django is empty for unknown reasons, while this is not the case with the flask app. request.body seems to mess things up but I am not entirely sure as I have ngrok in front of the app and at the same time it is not clear to me how wolt calculates the signature. I have confirmed with them that they have the correct SECRET_KEY. I will provide additional details soon.

I tried it with ngrok too, it worked fine. The payload being different is a very weird behavior. Good luck with it.
